Unable to publish python packages to Gitlab registry (due to 401 Unauthorized) using Poetry from within a CICD Job
I'm using the following three commands in my publish job to (attempt) push Python packages to the Gitlab registry. However, I get 401's and am unable to do so.
I'm using Poetry 1.8.3 in a python:3.12 runner image. I'm using Gitlab SAAS (not self-hosted)
    - poetry config repositories.gitlab "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi"
    - poetry config http-basic.gitlab gitlab-ci-token $CI_JOB_TOKEN
    - poetry publish -r gitlab -vvv  # dist/ exists locally with built artifacts for publishing

This publish URL came from the Gitlab docs, as did username and password variable. Googling also says these are correct.
Does anybody know what's up / what I need to change to enable publishing packages?
I can't seem to find vaguely referenced settings for enabling the group tokens (they're disabled and I can't find any way to create one), nor can I find any settings around permission scopes for CI_JOB_TOKENs

This is working fine on my side. The issue is from the permission of CI_JOB_TOKEN:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html:
To set a feature to be only visible to project members:

On the left sidebar, select Search or go to and find your project.
Select Settings > General.
Expand Visibility, project features, permissions.
Set the visibility to Only project members for the features you want to restrict access to.
The ability to fetch artifacts is controlled by the CI/CD visibility setting.
Select Save changes.

Another solution is using Project Access tokens:
In Settings > Access Tokens, you can create a token with api permission and at least developer role, and change CI_JOB_TOKEN to PRIVATE_TOKEN in your script, and save the secret in Settings > CI/CD.
